# Is every nowhere-zero pattern of residues realized by some prime number?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, ring-theory

Given a number $n$, define that its $n$-long sequence of residues is the sequence $n$ modulo $2$ up to $n$ modulo $p$, where $p$ is the $n$th prime number. For example, the $3$-long sequence of $10$ would be $(0,1,0).$ Obviously, prime numbers have no zeroes in their associated sequences. What I'd like to know is whether or not this is the *only* restriction.

> **Question.** Is it true that for all units $y \in \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \cdots \times \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, where $p$ is the $n$th prime, that there exists a prime $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ whose $n$-long sequence of residues equals $y$?
>
> (Requiring $y$ to be a unit amounts to requiring that each component be non-zero.)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adele_ring

Comment: @reuns, how does that help?

Comment: It reduces the question to asking whether you can find a prime in a particular arithmetic progression, and the. you can apply Dirichlet's theorem.